# Sankey Data formatting, presentation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, sankey-diagram

I'm trying to implement the Sankey plugin with d3.  I'm not getting the output I expected though. Hopefully someone can help.
I've reduced down to simplest possible dataset. 
There are 3 nodes. I would expect one link from Entry to Exit, and one going from Entry to Zone1, then Exit. Here is the set:

```
const graph = {
nodes: [
    {'node': 0, 'name': 'Entry'},
    {'node': 1, 'name': 'Zone 1'},
    {'node': 2, 'name': 'Exit'}
],
links: [
    {"source": 0, "target": 1, "value": 2},
    {"source": 1, "target": 2, "value": 2},
    {"source": 0, "target": 2, "value": 4}
]
}
```

However I'm just getting one link pathway, and also it looks kind of mashed up
[image]
Here is the link code:

```
var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link")
        .data(graph.links)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", path)
        .style("stroke-width", function (d) {
            return Math.max(1, d.dy);
        })
        .sort(function (a, b) {
            return b.dy - a.dy;
        });
    link.append("title")
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.source.name + " → " +
                d.target.name + "\n" + format(d.value);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

There was no explicit stroke color in the link code. I just needed to add:

```
.attr("stroke", "#CDCDCD")
```